# SQL, select sum of values by group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table product with the columns `id`, `stock` and `rate`.

I want a list of product with the sum of `stock` and the average `rate`.

The output in Oracle SQL needs to be as follows:

```
id      stock       rate
-------------------------
x        4            12.00
y        5            24.00
z        8             6.00
---------------------------
         17           14.00
```

Is it possible to write an SQL query that will give me the last row with 17 and 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the total with `rollup`.  But there is a trick, because the data is not aggregated.  So, aggregate by the `id`, which does nothing, but does allow the rollup to produce the total:

```
select id, sum(stock) as stock, avg(rate) as rate
from product
group by rollup(id);
```